# React-router: prevent navigation to target route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I'm using react-router with history `useQueries(createHashHistory)()` and I have several routes that I want to prevent navigation to based on route's configuration.
So routes config is like:

```
<Route path="/" name={RouteNames.APP} component={AppContainer}>
    <Route path="view-1"
        onEnter={ view1onEnter }
        onLeave={ view1onLeave }
        component={ View1 }
        canNavigate={ false }
    />
    <Route path="view-2"
        onEnter={ view2onEnter }
        onLeave={ view2onLeave }
        component={ View2 }
        canNavigate={ true }
    />
    ...
</Route>
```

So let's assume I'm on `#/view-2` and call an action like `history.push({pathname: '/view-1'});`. But as soon as route `view-1` has a flag `canNavigate={false}` - I want to prevent navigation to it and show a message **without changing a hash and any other side effects** (like calling `onLeave` hook of `view-2`).

I was thinking about listening to `history`:

```
history.listenBefore((location, callback) => {
    //e.g. callback(false) to prevent navigation
})
```

but I can't get the route instance to check `canNavigate` flag.
Later I've found out that `history` has a method `match` which actually gets next router state based on the given `location`:

```
history.listenBefore((location, callback) => {
    history.match(location, (error, redirectLocation, nextState) => {
        const route = _.last(nextState.routes);
        if (route.canNavigate) {
            callback();
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
})
```

but the problem is that `history.match` calls `onLeave` hook for `view-2` inside (which may, for example, clear state even though the user stays on the `view-2` view).

**The question**: is it possible to prevent navigation from `view-2` without any changes at all in history/router and making this decision based on target route configuration?

Answer (score 2):

React cannot prevent the navigation once you've called history.push.

You should encapsulate the history service with a custom one that will check whether it is possible to navigate and if it is then call history.push. otherwise prevent the navigation and keep the state.

Comment: Well, actually it [can](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v2.1.0/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md). The problem is that I have quite a lot of routes and want to get rid of check duplication.

Comment: By duplication, do you mean you don't want to check state if it's okay to navigate because each route already has a canNavigate props? Another thing, are the canNavigate props dynamic or static?

Comment: @JohnWilliamDomingo, `canNavigate` could be anything. In my particular case - it's a static property. And yes, you're right about duplication.